# Using htmlspecialchars within Query function

Tags: php, security, class, pdo, htmlspecialchars

Instead of manually adding the htmlspecialchars function to all outputted data, I've been trying to instead just place it in my query method so all returned data will automatically be processed.

This is my query method:

```
function query($query, $params=NULL) {
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query); 
    $execute = $stmt->execute($params);
    if($execute == false) {
        return false;
    }
    //return $stmt->fetchAll();
    $all_data = array();
    foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $value) {
        $all_data[] = array_map("htmlspecialchars", $value);
    }
    return $all_data;
}
```

For some reason, this only seems to work part of the time. I don't receive any errors, except just no data is returning.

What would be the best way to format this method to properly escape all data being outputted?

Comment: Be careful about escaping data for HTML too early.  You might need that data for something else later.  In my opinion, the best way to deal with this is to use a template engine and let that template engine take care of it.  Check out Smarty.

Comment: Yeah, you should never do that. This is your *database layer*, which deals with the database. HTML escaping is specific to the *presentation layer*, specifically the *HTML presentation layer*. You may have any number of other presentation types like JSON or email which have nothing to do with HTML but use the same database code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because its premise is flawed and the question becomes moot when best practices are followed. ;-)


Comment: What is the best way to escape data being passed to json?

Comment: You `json_encode` the whole array, no individual escaping needed.

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of manually adding the htmlspecialchars function to all outputted data, I've been trying to instead just place it in my query method so all returned data will automatically be processed.

This is a bad move. [Always escape on output, never on input](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/06/preventing-xss-vulnerabilities-in-php-everything-you-need-know). Aside from the "obvious" security benefit of output escaping over input escaping against an attacker with write access to your database, this allows you to get the original data and write unit tests to ensure it's output  correctly.

> What would be the best way to format this method to properly escape all data being outputted?

Since you're escaping on input and the original data is lost, there's no way to tell what's going wrong from the description given.

But generally, you want to use `htmlentities($string, ENT_HTML5 | ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')` (assuming your website uses UTF-8; select your encoding appropriately) instead of a naked `htmlspecialchars($string)`.